# express.js (static server) isn't loading my javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, express, server

My I'm using express.js as a static server and the code is looking like this:

```
var express = require('express'),
  app = express();

app
  .use(express.static('./public'))
  .get('*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile('public/main.html');
  })
  .listen(3000);
```

My file structure:

```
.
├── bower_components
│   ├── angular
│   ├── bootstrap
│   └── jquery
├── node_modules
│   └── express
├── public
│   ├── main.html
│   ├── src
│   └── views
└── server.js
```

My HTML is looking like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="ContactsApp">
<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title> Contacts </title>
  <base href="/" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/bootstrap.min.css"/>

</head>
 <body>    
  <script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="src/app.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

The Browser is not loading the angular library und I'm getting a error `Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js".`.

What I'm doing wrong? I couldn't find any answers from the previous questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line says that you are serving your static files from `./public`

```
use(express.static('./public'))
```

So only this tree will be exposed to the public:

```
   ├── main.html
   ├── src
   └── views
```

Your `bower_components` diretory is not in public, thus it is not exposed.

To fix this, you can create a `.bowerrc` file in the root of your application with the following:

```
{
  "directory": "public/bower_components/"
}
```

It will tell to `bower` to install the bower components in `public` instead of the default `bower_components` directory. Just run `bower install` after creating this file, and don't forget to update your `index.html` with the updated paths.

**EDIT:** Dont be tempted to change `use(express.static('./public'))` by `use(express.static('./'))` cause it will easily resolve your issue. It will expose your whole directory structure (and all your files) and is not good for obvious security reasons :)

Comment: You are right! The directory was not exposed to the static server.